# Get Location Updates While Device Is Powered

Tags: android, android-service, android-location

I'm trying to build an Android app that gets the location in the background the whole time the device is powered on.
Its used in a business situation and is permanently powered, so battery consumption is irrelevant.

On device boot, I enable a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, and start a location service which starts requesting location updates.

```
Intent intentLocation = new Intent(context, LocationService.class);
        context.startService(intentLocation);
```

In the onLocationChanged method I am processing the data.

But after a random amount of time, it could be half a day, or a couple of days, the app stops getting location updates.

When the app stops getting location updates, I either need to reboot the device or stop the app and start it again.

I assume Android is killing the process and its not restarting correctly even though I've specified START_STICKY?

Do I need to get location data in another thread or is there something else that I can do to ensure the location updates continue to come through?

This is my location class.

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {

public Context context;
private static final String TAG = "LocationService";

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location;    // location

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 10000;

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0;



/*
 * Callback that fires when the location changes.
 */
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged called");
    locationBroadcast(location);
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}



@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Turn on location services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d(TAG, "Network GPS provider being used");
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get location using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d(TAG, "GPS provider being used");
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Log.d(TAG, "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
    return START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    context = this;
    getLocation();
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}


private void locationBroadcast(Location currentLocation) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("gpsdata");
    sendLocationBroadcast(intent, currentLocation);
}


private void sendLocationBroadcast(Intent intent, Location currentLocation){

    JSONObject locationData = new JSONObject();
    try {
        locationData.put("latitude", currentLocation.getLatitude());
        locationData.put("longitude", currentLocation.getLongitude());
        locationData.put("altitude", Math.round(currentLocation.getAltitude()));
        locationData.put("accuracy", Math.round(currentLocation.getAccuracy()));
        locationData.put("speed", Math.round(currentLocation.getSpeed()));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }

    intent.putExtra("locationobject", locationData.toString());

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried using `startForeground()`?

Comment: @ArtyomDorosh I haven't tried that that but will give it ago. Does the startForeground command go in the onCreate or onStartCommand method?

Comment: no. You can call startForeground whenever you want.

Comment: Have you checked when location updates stop coming, the service is still running or not?

Comment: startForeground() has helped. When the GPS stops, I can just click a button in the mainActivity which restarts the GPS service back into life. But unfortunately, The GPS still stops providing updates. It happened on one of the devices around 6 hours after it was started, the service was still running but no updates.